# Logspout can't connect to papertrail

Tags: docker, networking, dns

I can't get [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) to connect to [papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/). I get the following error:

`!! lookup logs5.papertrailapp.com on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46185->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout`

where `46185` changes every time I run the container. It seems like a DNS error, but `nslookup logs5.papertrailapp.com` gives the expected output, as does `docker run busybox nslookup logs5.papertrailapp.com`.

Beyond that, I don't even know how to interpret that error message, let alone address it. Any help debugging this would be hugely appreciated.

---

My Docker Compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    logspout:
        image: gliderlabs/logspout
        command: "syslog://logs5.papertrailapp.com:12345"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    sleep:
        image: benwhitehead/env-loop
```

Where `12345` is the actual papertrail port. Result is the same whether using `syslog://` or `syslog-tls://`.

Comment: Can you post the commands you have used to setup the environment or if you are using docker-compose then post details of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker and iptables got in a fight. So I spun up a new machine, failed to set up iptables, and the problem was solved: no firewall at all to get in the way of Docker's connections!

Just kidding, don't do that. I got a toy database hacked that way.

Fortunately, it's now relatively easy to get iptables and Docker to live in harmony, using the `DOCKER_USER` iptables chain.

The solution, excerpted from [my blog](https://stderr.brandonistenes.com/firewalling-docker-with-iptables-finally-figured-out/):

Configure Docker with `iptables=true`, and append to iptables configuration:

```
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/:

> the docker daemon implements an embedded DNS server which provides built-in service discovery for any container

It looks like your container is unable to connect to this DNS server. If your container is on the default bridge network, it won't reach the embedded DNS server. You can either set `--dns` to be an outside source or update `/etc/resolv.conf`. It doesn't sound like a Papertrail issue, at all.

([source](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20026#issuecomment-180383581))

Comment: The problem diagnosis is certainly correct, that's definitely at least part of the problem. The solution didn't work though. I got the same error even when using the `--dns` flag. I eventually got so soul-crushingly frustrated I spun up a new machine and started over. It's working fine now.

Comment: I guess this is docker making good on its promise -- with everything dockerized, it's easy as pie to set up a new server once your old one is completely crippled with cryptic docker errors.